# How to move a space character from the front to the back of a letter

Tags: javascript

If a letter has a space in the back, move it to the frot like

ex: `" R"` → `"R "`,  `R` could be any letter. Any solution that works will do.

Comment: basic regular expression with replace.

Comment: MDN: [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: In the future, please consider doing more research, minor problems like these aren't the sort of questions StackOverflow is supposed to be used for, you could easily figure out a solution yourself (which is a learning opportunity as well).

Comment: @YannickK that's not right. Even beginner questions are welcome on SO.

Comment: @ToddChaffee I understand, but I was under the impression that every question needed to show some sort of evidence of prior research. To me this question reads as: "give me a solution to this problem I haven't tried to solve myself yet." I am relatively new as well though, so I'll accept your correction.

Comment: @YannickK if i knew what to search on google i would totally do it before asking a question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression along with 
String​.prototype​.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to move the space in front of any letter to the back of the letter:

```js
mystr = " R";

mystr = mystr.replace(/ ([a-zA-Z])/, "$1 ");

console.log(mystr);
```

Comment: great but i frogot to mention that this needs to be applied in a vector that looks like this "he", "ll" "o " "wo" "rl" "d " and if it moves a space it then needs to shift the vector so how can you do that ?

Comment: @EdwardC you should ask another question then and make that clearer. This answer works for the question you asked. If you do that, try to give code examples of what your variable should look like before and after.

Comment: @EdwardC I'm not sure what *shift the vector* means in this case. Questions about string manipulation (including regular expressions) need to be **extremely** specific. Include as many significant test cases as possible to help us know exactly what you want. It may also be helpful to include cases that should *not* be modified.

Comment: Ok I understand let me explain better here. If the vector is "hi" " w" "or" "ld" then we need to make the " w" to "w " and move the letters after it in front so it becomes "wo" "rl" "d".

Comment: @p.s.w.g more examples: " h" "el" "lo " -> **"he"** "ll" "o "    |||||                                                                                                "he" "ll" "o"  " s" "ta" "ck" -> "he" "ll" "o" **"st"** "ac" "k " please help me

Comment: @EdwardC Comment formatting is limited. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56297169/edit) your question to include the additional test cases.

Comment: @EdwardC this is a different question from your original question. I'll be happy to help you if you post a new question.

Comment: @ToddChaffee I think I found the solution. it may be inefficient but I really just need it to work. if I need any further help, I will post a new question